# Detect other dylib in a deb

Tags: deb, cydia-substrate

I made a tweak for Cydia. However, I want to make my dylib secure and can't be overwritten by "dpkg-repack". And ensure that if it got repacked by someone, it should detect it and stop the process/can't do anything.

I have some knowledge about Objective C; however, I cannot find anything related to it.

For example,
Deb have "test.dylib". Other person made a deb with dpkg-repack and named it "test1.dylib".

Installing it, test is working in background but it looked like test1 is doing all of the work.

Comment: Well, you can hook dpkg process and try to stop it from doing anything you don't want to.

Comment: How can you hook it?